# MySQL locking vs. SQLite locking

Tags: mysql, multithreading, sqlite, locking

In MySQL I am used to doing something like this:

```
LOCK TABLE theTable WRITE;
UPDATE theTable SET theValue = 123;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

If another process tries to update theTable while the above lock is in effect, it simply sleeps until the lock is removed and then continues normally. Race conditions are avoided.

I am now attempting to do something similar in SQLite3. So far I have tried:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
UPDATE theTable SET theVALUE=123;
COMMIT;
```

But in this case if another process attempts to update theTable while the above transaction is in effect, it fails with a "Database is locked" error.

Using SQLite3, how can I avoid a concurrent process from failing in case of simultaneous table updates and have it pause instead until the transaction has completed and the associated locks have been lifted, similar to MySQL's behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you mentioned with MySQL is app or driver specific. If you tried to run a separate UPDATE statement from the client, it should fail with a similar error. Ultimately, it's up to the client app to decide on the proper exception response. It can decide to postpone the update, or refuse it, or wait until the lock is cleared.

If you want a similar behavior in Sqlite, you should attempt the update in a while-type of loop so that it will retry until successful.

Comment: I'm trying to do this in PHP5, which behaves similar to the *ix MySQL and SLQite clients, respectively.

Comment: With MySQL, are you using ext/mysql, mysqli or PDO_MySQL? Also, are you using the native driver (mysqlnd) or libmysql?

Comment: Which minor version of PHP5?

Comment: I'm using ext/mysql and PHP 5.3.10.